# MVC Razor - If condition shows up in html render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In below code(the first Div) I need to Put if condition based on which different buttons will be visible. I did this but it results in below issue (see pic below). We can't put if conditions in DIV ? Please suggest a way to do this. Thanks!

[image]

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">  
                                    <div class="editDelGLCode">
                                        if(@Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                                        {
                                        <button type="button" class="btn OOrange" onclick="editGLCode(this);">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New
                                        </button>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <a href="#" title="Edit" onclick="editGLCode(this);"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="saveCanGLCode" style="display:none">
                                        <span id="UpdateOSaveGLCode"> <a href="#" title="Save" onclick="addOrUpdateOGlcode(this);"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></a></span>
                                        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span><a href="#" title="Cancel" onclick="cancelRowGLCode();"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hdnPM_GLCode" style="display:none;">
                                        @if (Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows.Count > 0)
                                        { @Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["BSAInfoRefID"]}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
```

Comment: The `Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length` check doesn't start with `@`, it's not part of Razor code (the correct one: `@if (Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)`).

Comment: add '@' before if(@Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0) also then you dont need @before model @ has been added before the c# code starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change This line of Code from :

```
if(@Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
```

To

```
@if(Model.Tables["PM_GLCode"].Rows[0]["InfoRefID"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
```

As `@` has to be added for the code logic starts

Comment: a stupid mistake. :(